# ActionStatus not showing startText

Tags: visualforce

When clicking the Selected Submissions button I'm seeing the ActionStatus displaying as 'Loading...' but the table is not updated to reflect the current selection option. Pic below shows the error.

[image]

```
<apex:actionRegion immediate="true" >
<!-- Selection List -->   
       <apex:selectList style="font-style:italic;color:blue" value="{!SelectedSubmissions}" multiselect="true"  disabled="{!statusupdate}">
         <apex:selectOptions value="{!SubmissionOptions}"/>
       </apex:selectList><p/>
</apex:actionRegion> 
<apex:actionRegion immediate="true" >
<apex:commandButton styleClass="button" style="background:lightgreen;color:white;border-radius:15px;" 
  value="Select Submissions" action="{!getSelectedSubmissions}" 
  rerender="outsubmission" status="status" 
  rendered="{! !statusupdate}"/>


</apex:actionRegion> 

<apex:actionRegion >
<apex:outputPanel id="outsubmission" layout="block" styleClass="header1" >

<apex:actionstatus id="status" startText="loading...">
<apex:facet name="stop">
<apex:outputPanel >

<br></br>
<apex:dataTable styleClass="alldatatables" headerClass="alldatacols" columnClasses="alldatacols" rowClasses="alldatarows"  value="{!submissionList}" var="s" rules="all" cellpadding="5" rows="1" >
<!-- <apex:column value="{!s.name}"/> -->                                
<apex:column value="{!s.Producing_Broker_Full__c}" headerValue="Producing Broker - Location" headerClass="TableTitle" />                            
<!--  <apex:column value="{!s.Key_Broker_Contact_LU_PS__c}" headerValue="Key Contact" /> -->
</apex:dataTable> 

<html>
<body>
<br></br>

<br></br>
<p style="font-size:15px;font-weight:bold;color:black">Selected Submissions</p>

<div style="overflow-x:auto;">
<table class="htmlDataTable" > 
<br></br>
<thead>
<tr>
<th> Contracts </th>
<th> Key Contact </th>
<th> Effective Date </th>
<th> N/R </th>

</tr>
</thead>
<apex:repeat value="{!submissionList}" var="s" >
<tr> 
<td>{!s.SPD_REF_PS__c}</td>
<td><apex:outputField style="color: blue" value="{!s.Key_Broker_Contact_LU_PS__c}" /></td><!-- bug with outputfield style not rendering font color. -->

<td>
<apex:outputText value="{0,date,MM/dd/yy}" >
<apex:param value="{!s.Est_CERT_Incept_Date_PS__c}" />
</apex:outputText>
</td>

<td>{!s.Submission_New_Renew_PS__c}</td> 

</tr> 
</apex:repeat>
</table> 
</div>
</body>
</html>

</apex:outputPanel>
</apex:facet>
</apex:actionstatus>

</apex:outputPanel>
</apex:actionRegion>
<br></br>
```

Comment: I now get the status message but the html table is not loading with current query data. Appended to the bottom of the table is: 'window.parent.SfdcApp.Visualforce.viewstate.ViewInstance.reload();window.parent.SfdcApp.Visualforce.viewstate.ViewInstance.reload(); '

Comment: put a picture of your issue so that members can understand and able to guide you

Comment: Added picture. By removing the actionSupport and placing the rerender on the commandButton I am seeing the status text. However, the table is not being reloaded with the current selected option from the query action.

Comment: if you use `actionRegion` surrounding a commandButton, then on click, only the values within the `actionRegion` are sent to the server (controller). See [VF doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionRegion.htm)

Answer (score 1):

I think main issue here is using `immediate="true"` in `actionRegion`. Using `immediate="true"` not only omits validations on UI, but also do not fire setter values in the controller.

```
<apex:actionRegion>
    <apex:commandButton styleClass="button" style="background:lightgreen;color:white;border-radius:15px;" 
      value="Select Submissions" action="{!getSelectedSubmissions}" 
      rerender="outsubmission" status="status" 
      rendered="{! !statusupdate}"/>
</apex:actionRegion>
```

Also, place debug in `getSelectedSubmissions` method to verify if your are getting selected values

Comment: I dropped the immediate="true" . Still no effect on the table picking up new queries. Wondering if I need to wrap the command button and the table in the same action region ?

Comment: command button and table should be different actionRegion, use apex:param to pass picklist value to controller

Comment: Interesting. I just updated the code to include the selected options. Originally was using dataTables so this just worked. But implementing html to reduce the view state. How would you suggest using apex:param given the selected options above.

Comment: Santanu - if the OP is expecting values in the table to be transmitted to the controller on click of commandButton, then the actionRegion needs to be bigger in scope, no?